# how to make condition to a specific groups

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I want to add a condition to one group access to no open and no create_edit just for normal people, but when I use the code below the admin have no access to edit I give to him all access right to file security

```
<field name="name" domain="[('person_id', '=', person_id), ]"                                
options='{"no_open":True,"no_create_edit": True}' readonly="1"
  />
```

Comment: Already tried access rights for your user group?

Comment: Do you want to do something like a specific group peoples can not able to open form view and can not able to create_edit_delete any data. Right ?

Comment: yes  create_edit for specific group

Answer (score 0):

No way to get it done without Odoo core extension to provide that features or by overriding the method `fields_view_get` to dynamically change the view definition based on the user groups.